# Sound format for mobile browser with construct 2 game engine

Tags: android, ios, audio

I am working in a project to build a game using [construct 2 game engine](http://www.scirra.com/).
The game is for mobile devices, the sound is in ogg format, I tested it in android 2.3(on a real device) and its work (big latency,but works). In iOS it is not working (iOS 5.0.1 on device and 4.3/5.1 on emulator).

I tested it in safari desktop browser -> not working, but if I change to m4a format -> it works (not in iOS)

What do I have to do to make it work in both Android and iOS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To have audio play on all platforms, you need both an .m4a file and a .ogg file for each sound.  For example, gunfire.m4a and gunfire.ogg.

Construct 2 automatically encodes .ogg when importing a WAV file, and will automatically encode a .m4a if you're on Windows 7.  However if you're on Windows XP or Vista it won't encode this audio for you, because of licensing issues (it's not a free format).  You should be able to find your own encoder though.  Just encode the files yourself and import the .m4a files to Construct 2 with the same name as the corresponding .ogg.  Search Google for "AAC encoder" and you should find something pretty quick.